# Why is my PHP copy() function creating a blank file?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, copy, ubuntu-16.04

I have a copy function per say:

```
<?php
 copy ( "$source" , "$destination" );
?>
```

The code does create a copy succssfully however the $destination (or copied file) is left blank. if i open it it is empty unlike the $source file.

The file size is 0b.

My situation:

nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)

PHP 7.0.13-0

ubuntu0.16.04.1

The file permissions for the code processing file is 0777

The permission for the source file is 0777

The file permission for the destination file after being copyed (the blank one ) : 0644.

Obviously no control over the permission before copying.

Anyone know the reason for this and how to make the php copy() function copy the file with the original file contents?

Best regards,

AT

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i seemed to solve this apparently my server ran out of disk space.

Makes sense. should have known.